# Using a do while loop in Linux to return certain values

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a script that essentially checks if a file is being updated. If the file is being updated at that moment then the script does nothing, but if the file has stopped updating, then the script needs to return some other statement.

So far I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/home/

cd $DIR

FILE=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -1 -name 'test.log' | wc -l)

while [ ${FILE} -eq 1 ]
do
    echo "Now sleeping for 20 seconds"
    sleep 20
done
if [ ${FILE} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Job is finished"
fi
```

Basically I am looking in my home directory for a file called test.log that has been updated within 1 minute. I'm using wc -l to show that the file exists. I want to use the while loop to return the statement "Now sleeping for 20 seconds" if the test.log file exists. Once the file is no longer updated, I want the script to move on and return "Job is finished".

So far, when running the script when the test.log file does not exist, Job is finished is returned. However, when the test.log file is there and is only '1 minute old' or less, the script returns "Now sleeping for 20 seconds", and continues to return this even when the file is older than 1 minutes and is not updating anymore. The script never moves on to return "Job is finished"

Comment: You need to repeat the `FILE=$(...` line just after the `sleep 20` to update the thing being tested. Having said that this could be improved. You don't need to count the number of lines with `wc -l`, you can just see if the output of find is empty or not. You don't need the final `if`, you can just print "Job is finished". You might look at the `fuser` command to see if the file is open rather than using the file not being modified for a minute as the test.

Answer (score 3):

You are not modifying the `FILE` variable inside the loop (so it stays constant), and so either finish immediately or enter an infinite loop.

Assuming your linux system has the `stat` command, try

```
while (( ( $(printf "%(%s)T") - $(stat -c"%Y" test.log) ) < 60 ))
  do    echo "Now sleeping for 20 seconds"
        sleep 20
  done
```

It makes use of `bash` 's features `%()T` and `((...))`, and the `stat` epoch format for easy subtraction of the two time values. If the file changes within a minute, it keeps looping, until file is older than one min.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while-loop that loops forever and `break` the loop if the file is not found. You need to move the `find` command inside the loop for repeated checks:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    logfile=$(find /home -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -1 -name 'test.log')

    if [ -z "$logfile" ]; then
      break # no file found, break while-loop
    fi
    echo "Now sleeping for 20 seconds"
    sleep 20
done
echo "Job is finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -1 -name 'test.log' | wc -l)
```

The command substitution is expanded and `find` launched right here, when the assignment is made. You're not changing `FILE` anywhere else so it will keep the value it got at the start of the script. Move the command substitution and assignment inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Distilling @Freddy's solution slightly:

```
#!/bin/bash

while find /home -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -1 -name 'test.log' | grep -q .
do
    echo "Now sleeping for 20 seconds"
    sleep 20
done
echo "Job is finished"
```

This solution uses `grep`'s `-q` switch to suppress the usual output of grep, which simply tests the output of `find` for an empty/not empty condition.  The `while` loop will continue to loop so long as the `find` command outputs at least one line of text.  Once the `test.log` file is older than one minute, `find` no longer produces any output, and the `grep` command fails, causing the loop to terminate.

Comment: This solution seemed to work fine except I had to take away the ! and the start of the find command. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, @May. Yes, my bad, I'll edit that out. I misread the `find` man page regarding `-mmin -1` versus `-mmin +1`. Thanks for the feedback!